# Can't set custom status code message in HTTP Response with Cake PHP

Tags: php, http, cakephp, cakephp-3.3

I want to modify the reponse in a controller method. I figured out how to change the status code, but I can't change the message. 
The [API](https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Network.Response.html#_httpCodes) says to give to the `httpCodes` method an array in which for each code, the message we want to set. Here is my code :

```
$this->response->statusCode(400);   
$this->response->httpCodes(array(400 => 'Origin Denied'));
return $this->response;
```

And I get `Bad Request` instead of `Origin Denied`.

I also tried to directly set the header like this :

```
$this->response->header("HTTP/1.0 500 Invalid file name.");
```

or

```
$this->response->header("HTTP/1.0", "500 Invalid file name.");
```

But I get

```
 "HTTP/1.0 500 Invalid file name." is not valid header name : InvalidArgumentException
```

I'm on Cake PHP 3.3 and PHP 7.1. The goal of this is to upload medias on my website and to get back a JSON structure with the file location, or an appropriate code if it fails. This is TinyMCE requirements.

I'm a beginner with CakePHP and the Response class, I read the book and the API but I still don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I'd like to note that such a requirement seems rather inconvenient. If the reponse is to be expected to have a body in JSON format, then the custom reason phrase could be easily defined just in there.

### `Response::httpCodes()` only works with the "old" front controller

That being said, generally this is possible, but when using the PSR compatible request/reponse components introduced with CakePHP 3.3, this is currently not directly supported, as custom reason phrases will not be passed over to the PSR compatible response. With the pre 3.3 dispatching mechanisms it will still work however, check the "old" application templates front controller (`webroot/index.php` file).

### Can be done easily again as of 3.4

As of CakePHP 3.4, `Response::httpCodes()` is deprecated, and it will be removed in 4.0. Also as of 3.4, the CakePHP response class will be fully PSR-7 compatible, and you will be able to set statuses with custom reason phrases via the `Response::withStatus()` method, like

```
return $this->response->withStatus(400, 'Bad Origin');
```

Have in mind that the PSR-7 compatible reponse objects are immutable! ie, if you wish to modify `$this->response` in your controller for further use, you'd have to overwrite it, like:

```
$this->response = $this->response->withStatus(/* ... */);
```

### Requires "workaround" in 3.3/3.4 transition

In the transition between 3.3 and 3.4, when using the PSR compatible front controller, you can add support for custom reason phrases by overriding `Application::__invoke()` (the `Application` class file is by default located in your apps `src` folder.

You'd have to reimplement the `BaseApplication::__invoke()` code, and pass over the reason phrase obtained from `Response::httpCodes()`, something along the lines of:

```
use Cake\Http\RequestTransformer;
use Cake\Http\ResponseTransformer;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

// ...

public function __invoke(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $next)
{
    $cakeRequest = RequestTransformer::toCake($request);
    $cakeResponse = ResponseTransformer::toCake($response);

    $cakeResponse = $this->getDispatcher()->dispatch($cakeRequest, $cakeResponse);

    $psrResponse = ResponseTransformer::toPsr($cakeResponse);

    $status = $psrResponse->getStatusCode();
    $httpCodes = $cakeResponse->httpCodes($status);
    if ($httpCodes !== null && isset($httpCodes[$status])) {
        return $psrResponse->withStatus($status, $httpCodes[$status]);
    }

    return $psrResponse;
}
```

### See also

- **[Cookbook > Middleware > PSR7 Requests and Responses](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html#psr7-requests-and-responses)**
- **[Cookbook > Upcoming 3.4 Migration Guide](https://book.cakephp.org/3.next/en/appendices/3-4-migration-guide.html)**
- **[API 3.4 > \Cake\HTTP\Client\Response::withStatus()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Http.Client.Response.html#_withStatus)**
- **[Source > Pre 3.3 front controller](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.2.6/webroot/index.php)**
- **[Issues > #9516 > Cannot send a custom status text](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/9516)**
- **[PHP FIG > PSR-7](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/)**

Comment: That's a hell of a response. Thank you for explaining further more :)

Comment: Upvote for spotting out that $this->response is immutable: $this->response = $this->response->withStatus(/* ... */);

Answer (score 0):

First, the link you provided is for Cake2, not 3

And for the status code, the `400` code is associated with the message `Bad request` and you can't change it.

And headers are set in this way where $header is prefixed with `X-`

```
$this->response->header($header, $valueOfTheHeader);
```

Comment: Woops, my bad. But it's the same. Yes I know and I tried many things but still I can't change the message.. With `$this->response->header("HTTP/1.0", "500 Invalid file name.");
` I get `"HTTP/1.0" is not valid header name `. There is no way to change the message ?

Comment: not that i am aware of.  here is the list of valid http headers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Comment: You can set custom headers by prefixing them with `X-` Example `$this->response->header('X-customeheader', 'Some value');`